# Thermostat Wiring for Zoned Hydronic Heating

Tags: electrical, thermostat, boiler, water-circulating-heating, relay

I have a 7 zone circulator pump heated using Navien combi-boiler. 3 thermostats are connected to the boiler, and the remaining 4 are connected to a Taco SR-504 relay. All the connections have 2 wires, R and W.

Even though each thermostat is able to control the corresponding pump, only the thermostats connected to the boiler is able to call for hot water to supply heating. So if any of the 4 were to call for heating, one of the other 3 would need to be on as well for it to actually heat up. Would pigtailing the other 4 thermostat wires to the boiler work to fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You would need to provide a good deal more information about the details of how the present wiring is connected. Presumably there should be a connection (missing or broken) from the Taco relay to the boiler to call for heat. The instructions suggest that, explicitly. https://www.tacocomfort.com/documents/FileLibrary/102-381.pdf Which terminals to where depends on the boiler type.

Comment: Hi there, the boiler model is Navien NCB-250/150H. I've added pictures of the wiring.
4 thermostat wires connected to the boiler, 3 to thermostat terminal and 1 to recirculation; and 5 thermostat wires connected to relay

Comment: You have the "Isolated End Switch" terminals connected on the relay box, which should be connected to your boiler already, according to the manual linked above. Can you trace those wires and see where they go?

Comment: Based on the labels that the installer tagged, the isolated end switch wire should be connected to the recirculation terminal of the boiler.

Comment: Dumb question - have you checked the fuses? If things are wired right, and used to work, and the wires haven't been chewed (or sometimes if they have, and caused it) a fuse might have blown. If it never worked right, more likely a misplaced wire or choice of wrong terminals (or even a DIP switch setting.)

Comment: As far as I know, it has never worked correctly. I was told an electrician looked at this in the past and said this configuration is not possible since the boiler only has 3 thermostat terminals. Could you let me know what I can do to troubleshoot this type of setup?

Comment: Probably dig into the boiler manual and find out where those wires really should go.

Comment: Have you checked if the "external recirculation" setting is turned on? Without it, those terminals will be ignored.

Comment: Is there a dedicated recirculation setting for space heating? I can only find external recirculation setting in the DHW operation and it is off.